# Android studio : How do I retrieve specific data from Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

```
private TextView welcomeText;
DatabaseReference databaseReference = database.getReference("Users").child("name");
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qayc6.png

What I want to do is retrieve the data "name" from the Firebase database and setText for the welcomeText to the data "name".

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
 DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    reference.child("Users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                //model class assign
                ModelClass Class = dataSnapshot.getValue(ModelClass.class);
                String name = cartClass.getName();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the help but what is cartClass? And another question, I do get an error for the .getName() function.

Comment: For Example classname  call CartClass

Comment: how did you save the data in firebase realtime database ?

Comment: Oh, I did a registration system.

Comment: please explain clearly

Answer (score 0):

Hey I hope you going fantastic. Make sure you have inserted your DB URL from Firebase in your FirebaseDatabase object in your code before coding the query.
So in order your project is ready you need to read the following path: *DB > users > UserID > name* to reach the value you are looking for. If you want to change 'name' into all of your firebase database registers you should try this.

```
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance('FirebaseDBURL').getReference();

    reference.child("Users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                //Here you are reading all of your Users objects
                if(dataSnapshot.getKey.equals('name')){ //Here we are identifying the attr you want to change by its key name
                    String text = reference.child("Users").child(datasnapshot.getValue()).getValue(String.class);
yourEditText.setText(text);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```

I hope you solve your issue. However here you have such an [usefull info](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data):`

Comment: Hello there. Thank you for taking your time and explaining the logic behind Firebase DB. I know this is only a rookie issues since I'm still new. But actually all I want to to get the data called "name", not change it. Just retrieve the string data and put in into a TextView class.

Comment: Hey there friend I hope you can solve your problem with the new actualization I did on my post, I would recommend you to check the Firebase documentation in order you want to learn more about android studio. Also I encourage you to check out some youtube tutorials related to Android Studio + Firebase to establish the learning quickly :).